# jQuery UI droppable not re-enbled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I have a board game with a grid. each square in the grid has a class `.unitPosition` which is the droppable for the units. I want to prevent more then 1 unit being at the same square so I disable droppable on `drop` and re-enable it on `out`. The problem is that the re-enabling is not working.

```
$(".unitPosition").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable
            .detach()
            .css({top: 0,left: 0})
            .appendTo($(this));
        $(this).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(this).parent());
        $(this).droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
    }
});
```

I tried a basic version of this and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/vMQVy/40/

**UPDATE:**

This is the fiddle where it is **not** working: http://jsfiddle.net/FbzSF/3/

Comment: your jsfiddle snipped seems to work fine for me?

Comment: @simplyray I added one that doesn't

Comment: Found the Problem: `The event out is triggerd when you hover a draggable over a droppable and then move it away. Unfortunately not when you drag a draggable away.` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469879/jquery-droppable-out-event-fails-to-trigger

Comment: @simplyray thanx! why comment? this is an answer

Comment: Changed it and added the comment as anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem:

> The event out is triggerd when you hover a draggable over a droppable
>   and then move it away. Unfortunately not when you drag a draggable
>   away.

See: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1469879/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469879/)